# How to re-open an existing SpringRoo project?

Tags: spring, console, spring-roo

Perhaps a stupid newbie question: How to re-open an existing [roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html) project and add new fields or entities without erasing existing data, e.g.:

```
roo.sh
  project  --topLevelPackage de.test.model
  jpa setup  --provider HIBERNATE  --database MYSQL 
  entity jpa  --class de.test.model.Person
  field string  --fieldName name
quit

roo.sh
  field string  --fieldName surname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry, looking at the commands you have issued it will not erase your existing data. You will need to execute the `focus` command in order to make sure the Roo console is currently focused on the entity you are adding fields to.

```
roo> focus --class com.foo.Blah
~.Blah roo>
```

You can find out the history of this command at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-784.

Cheers.